# How to edit Subject line in mail?

Tags: gmail

There doesn't seem to be a way to edit the subject line in received mail.  I've tried forwarding it to myself, or reply, but neither has a drop down menu I can find that allows me to edit the subject.

Comment: "Reply" first, then edit the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the reply arrow:

[image]

A dropdown box will appear with the option to edit subject.